# Can't install webkit-server

Tags: python, windows, cmd, environment-variables

(PYTHON 2.7) I'm trying to install **webkit-server**. The problem is that it returns this error:

```
running install
running build
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'
```

Do you have any idea how to avoid this error? Or is there a msi or exe setup for **webkit-server**?

Comment: You don't have make installed or it is not in your path.

Comment: Thanks, how could I install 'make'?

Comment: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows